# Value retrieval from the multiple selection dropdown in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, dropdownlist

I am trying to make calculation from my dropdown menu. I have following dropdown in sheet 1 in my Excel.

```
## Category ##
### AAA ###
### BBB ###
### CCC ###
### DDD ###
```

In sheet 2, I have corresponding values for this dropdown.

```
## Category  Category Value##
### AAA    1###
### BBB    2###
### CCC    3###
### DDD    4###
```

I added VBA code for multiple selection and also added simple `VLOOKUP` formula to retrieve the value of category.

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;Sheet2!I2:J5;2;)
```

With the VBA code, I am able to select all three category and also remove the selected category later. But I am failing to retrieve the sum of selected category. E.g., if a customer chooses category AAA & CCC, he/she should be able to see sum as 4. Also, if a customer first chooses all three categories and then removes one of them, then the sum should get updated. I am not getting how do I update my `VLOOKUP` formula to get the sum.

Here is my VBA code for multiple selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated: 2016/4/12
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                '                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
                '                   InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) Or _
                InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") Then
                If InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, xValue2 & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, ", " & xValue2, "") ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Then        ' If it is the only item in string
                    xValue1 = ""
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
            End If
            jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First, your `VLOOKUP` is messed up. You should use `VLOOKUP(E2;Sheet2!$I$2:$J$5;2;0)`. `$I$2:$J$5` instead of your `I2:J5`, so that when you copy the formula down, your lookup range does not go down too. `0` at the end is necessary for finding *exactly* what is in `E2`, `E3`, etc. If you omit the `0`, your results are no longer reliable, because then `VLOOKUP` may do approximations which you will not anticipate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND(Sheet2!$I$2:$I$5;A1;1));0;Sheet2!$J$2:$J$5))
```

This must work, but it is not a regular formula. It is an *array* formula. For array formulas to work, you enter it *not* with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but instead use a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also, change the `A1` to your actual dropdown cell.

[image: Example]